# Modulus of complex numbers problem draw the loci

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $|z − 3| + |z + 3| = 12$,  $z = x + iy$, find the expression in terms of $x$ and $y$ and draw the loci.

I've tried many ways and I cannot isolate $x$ or $y$. I think that is necessary put the equation in this form $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2$. 
May someone help me?

Comment: Would you like to include the equation that you can't isolate $x$ or $y$ in your post? Typing tips, surround mathematical object with dollar signs and use \sqrt{x} for $\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

Geometric hint: the locus of points $z$ whose sum of distances to fixed points $-3$ and $3$ is a constant, in this case $12\,$, is an ellipse.

Setting $y=0$ gives the intersections with the real axis as $x = \pm 6\,$, and setting $x=0\,$ gives the intersections with the imaginary axis as $y=\pm 3 \sqrt{3}\,$.

The [equation of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equation) centered at the origin and having a horizontal axis, with semi major axis $a=6$ and semi minor axis $b=3\sqrt{3}\,$, is $\,\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1\,$.

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy$ where $x,y$ are real

For
$$\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}+\sqrt{(x+c)^2+y^2}=2a$$

$$(x+c)^2+y^2=4a^2+(x-c)^2+y^2-4a\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}$$

$$\iff a\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2}=a^2-cx$$

Squaring we get  $$a^2\{(x-c)^2+y^2\}=a^4-2a^2cx+c^2x^2$$

$$\iff(a^2-c^2)x^2+a^2y^2=a^2(a^2-c^2)$$

For $a\ne c,$  $$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{y^2}{a^2-c^2}=1$$